# How to declare a Typed Class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I need to declare an instance of `Map.class`, but the Map is typed... So I need something like this:

```
Class <Map<String, String>> clazz = Map.class;
```

This line causes a compile error. What is the clean way of expressing this?

Comment: Could you provide some insight on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @alexk, I have a situation where I am invoking a method that receives a `Class<T>` as a parameter. In my case, it would be the `Class<Map<String, String>`. If I write `Map.class`, it works fine, but I dislike the warning... I'm looking for a way to get rid of the warning (not using `@SupressWarnings`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with casts.

```
Class<Map<String, String>> clazz = (Class<Map<String, String>>) (Object) Map.class;
```

This generates a warning but compiles.

The problem with it is that due to type erasure, the resulting object at runtime is no different from `Map.class` (it doesn't know about the type).

If you need an object that truly represents `Map<String, String>` you can look into using `java.lang.reflect.Type` or Guava's `TypeToken`.

Comment: Excellent answer, sir. I've learned something new.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: This works so far, but I don't like to do casting... I would like some solution that doesn't involve casting, or better said, that doesn't generate warnings (@SupressWarnings is not a solution, just a workaround)...

Comment: I agree this is not a satisfactory solution. There is no way of doing this without a warning sadly.

Comment: Based on this last comment, I will accept the answer... There is indeed no "100% clean" way of doing it...

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String [] args){
   Class <Map> clazz = Map.class;
   System.out.println(clazz);
  }
}
```

will print

> interface java.util.Map

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> clazz = new HashMap<String, String>()
```

Remember that Map is an interface, not instantiable directly but only via a class implementing it, like `HashMap` or `TreeMap`

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in Java, you can't use it as a variable name

Comment: The OP needs a Class, not a Map.

Comment: @JonK right, I did not care the name of the variable. thx.

Comment: @morels: I think here the OP has another problem. You can get a `Class<Map>` object from an interface. But here he has a typed Map, not a raw Map, so the compiler won't let him get a `Class<Map<String, String>` object. Sorry, but I'm downvoting until you edit your answer.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. OP wants a Class type and not an instance of a Map.